# Hide only One div to same id

Tags: jquery

I have Two Div ids with same name, but I Want to Only One Div So What can i do?

```
<div id="redeemedpointsdetaildiv" class="redeemedpointsdetaildiv">
</div>

<div id="redeemedpointsdetaildiv" class="redeemedpointsdetaildiv">
</div>
```

Comment: ID should be unique. Why you are having same id for two Div's?

Comment: Do not use duplicate `id`.

Comment: Yah I know but this is my situation

Comment: Which one you need to hide? First Div or second?

Comment: If you use class then you can access all div object that has `class-name` and for `id` you will get only first div. For that you can use `$(".redeemedpointsdetaildiv:first")` or `:last` or `:eq(2)` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working good --> Parth Trivedi

Comment: Welcome. As someone added my comment in answer i am not put it in answer. btw it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: duplicate id is not a good thing.
If you use `class` then you can access all `div` object that has `class-name` and for `id` you will get only **first div**.
To `hide` only one `div` you need to use the `class` and `eq` selector:

This hide the first div:

```
$(".redeemedpointsdetaildiv:eq(0)").hide();
```

This hide the second div:

```
$(".redeemedpointsdetaildiv:eq(1)").hide();
```

Comment: Good answer needs to cover more explanation so for other it can be more usable for future.

Comment: You're right. I'm not english and sometimes it's hard to explain. Thanks a lot for your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".redeemedpointsdetaildiv:gt(0)").hide();
```

The [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector selects elements with an index number higher than a certain number