# How to retrieve the value with same Ids in input tag?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 input tage with same ids but i Want to retrieve first input tag value 1 What can i do..

```
<td>
   <input id="monetaryvalue_new0" class="monetaryvalue_new smallInputBox" type="text"  value="1" name="monetaryvalue_new0" rownumber="0" readonly="">
</td>

<td>
   <input id="monetaryvalue_new0" class="monetaryvalue_new smallInputBox" type="text" value="0" name="monetaryvalue_new0" rownumber="0" readonly="">
</td>
```

Comment: Can not use duplicate `id` for that you have to access via `class`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of your question . Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692934/hide-only-one-div-to-same-id

Comment: yah I know Path but i do not how to auto generated with same ids

Comment: Please elaborate your problem so other can give better way to do this.

Comment: Why you want to give DOM elements with same ID and same class ????

Comment: The error is that you are using non-unique IDs. You say they're autogenerated, so show us how you're generating them. That will be the part of your code you need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
$('[id="monetaryvalue_new0"]').eq(0)
                              .eq(1)
```

and let the Jquery frame work to search the elements for you. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of `id` like below. It is not good idea to use same `id` for multiple element.

```
$('.monetaryvalue_new').eq(0).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids have to be unique on each page. The best way to get the value in your case would be to use the class.

```
$('.monetaryvalue_new0').eq(0).val();
```